# Play! Framework - Spring.getBeanOfType works but @Autowired fails

Tags: spring, playframework, autowired

I am using `play spring-1.0.1` [module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/spring-1.0.1/home) and as per the documentation :

> ```
> To enable component scanning, add this line to the
> ```
>
> /conf/application.conf file:
>
> ```
> play.spring.component-scan=true
> Note that enabling this scans for @org.springframework.stereotype.Component,
> ```
>
> @org.springframework.stereotype.Repository,
>   @org.springframework.stereotype.Service
>   to identify Spring beans.
>   Additionally, running the component
>   scan enables support for annotation
>   based configuration (i.e.,
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired,
>   etc).

When I try the same thing, it fails saying `NullPointerException`, since it is not able to wireup the beans to the corresponding class.

Although

```
play.modules.spring.Spring.getBeanOfType(UserManager.class);
```

just works fine on my models.
Is it a known issue or I am doing it incorrectly

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what your class looks like that you are trying to resolve?